Filter pandas dataframe between dates located in another dataframe
Suppose I have two pandas dataframes: A first dataframe with some data (reflected in columns Col1 and Col2 in example below) across both Code and Time.
A second dataframe detailing a set of date bounds. The idea is to exclude any rows (in df_table) that have a date that falls between any bounds (in df_dates). Each Code has one or more (and different) bounds or may not have bounds at all.
The code below works well and does the task correctly but it takes way too much time (the first dataframe df_table has several million rows).
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def filter_date(main_table, table_dates):
    
    idx = table_dates.Code == main_table.Code
    table_dates = table_dates.loc[idx]
    filtering = (table_dates['Start Date'] <= main_table.Timestamp) & (table_dates['End Date'] >= main_table.Timestamp)
    
    return filtering.any()


# Example below
df_table = pd.DataFrame({'Code':['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'], 'Timestamp':[1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2], 'Col1':np.arange(14), 'Col2':np.arange(14)})
df_dates = pd.DataFrame({'Code':['A', 'A', 'B'], 'Start Date':[1, 5, 1], 'End Date':[2, 6, 3]})
        
df_table['Exclude Date'] = df_table.apply(lambda x: filter_date(x, df_dates), axis=1)
df_table = df_table[df_table['Exclude Date'] == False]
        
print(df_table)

Is there a smarter way to do this and avoid this .apply()?

Why didn't you just merge?

@rpanai I could merge both dataframes on 'Code' but then I am running into a memory issue. It says it is unable to allocate 15 GiB

how duplicated are your Code columns? trying to figure out where the bottleneck is. if it is a many to many join, then it may be an issue

@sammywemmy - Not sure I got your question correctly but there is approx. 7-8 years of data (in business days - so potentially 250*7=1750+ days). One code name could therefore appear in 1750+ rows in df_table. There are 3k+ codes. Now the other table has on average 10-20 different data bounds per code

is Code unique in both dataframes? if it is duplicated (repeated values), then you will have a many to many join, which may explain the blow out. if we can confirm the uniqueness or non uniqueness, we can possibly approach the challenge with a different solution.

Column Code has repeated values in each DataFrame. In my first example, the value 'A' is repeated multiple times in both df_table and df_dates and it is why it is blowing out I believe.

is the actual data shareable? one suggestion is to create temporary numeric columns for the Code - need to hit the road, but have a look at janitor.conditional_join and see if it helps, especially the numba code. if you can get Code to numeric form, you may get some perf since the non equi part is a range join

Unfortunately I can't share the data. I will have a look at this conditional_join. I can try to run Adeva1's code as well to see.

You can try something like this:
1.Create a dictionary with ranges for each Code
2.Check if the Timestamp value exists in the range for that code
3.Add a column with Yes and No values. You can then group the dataframe on the basis of this.
It seems longer but checking the values of a list in a dictionary is quicker.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Example below
df_table = pd.DataFrame({'Code':['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'], 'Timestamp':[1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2], 'Col1':np.arange(14), 'Col2':np.arange(14)})
df_dates = pd.DataFrame({'Code':['A', 'A', 'B'], 'Start Date':[1, 5, 1], 'End Date':[2, 6, 3]})
        
#Create Dictionary with boundary ranges for each code value
ranges = {k: [] for k in df_dates['Code'].unique()}

for i in range(len(df_dates)):
    row = df_dates.loc[i]
    ranges[row['Code']].append((row['Start Date'], row['End Date']))


#Check if 'Timestamp' values are in the range and add a 'Yes, 'No' and 'NaN' column
within_boundary = []    
for i in range(len(df_table)):
    row = df_table.loc[i]
    if row['Code'] in (ranges.keys()):
        
        if any(lower <= row['Timestamp'] <= upper for (lower, upper) in ranges[row['Code']]):
            within_boundary.append('Yes')
        else:
            within_boundary.append('No')
    else:
        within_boundary.append('NaN')
        

df_table['Within_Boundary'] = within_boundary      
print(df_table)

Output:
  Code  Timestamp  Col1  Col2 Within_Boundary
0     A          1     0     0             Yes
1     A          2     1     1             Yes
2     A          3     2     2              No
3     A          4     3     3              No
4     A          5     4     4             Yes
5     A          6     5     5             Yes
6     B          1     6     6             Yes
7     B          2     7     7             Yes
8     B          3     8     8             Yes
9     B          4     9     9              No
10    B          5    10    10              No
11    B          6    11    11              No
12    C          1    12    12             NaN
13    C          2    13    13             NaN

Checking if the new solution is faster :
import timeit

def function1():
           
    df_table = pd.DataFrame({'Code':['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'], 'Timestamp':[1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2], 'Col1':np.arange(14), 'Col2':np.arange(14)})
    df_dates = pd.DataFrame({'Code':['A', 'A', 'B'], 'Start Date':[1, 5, 1], 'End Date':[2, 6, 3]})
            
    #Create Dictionary with boundary ranges for each code value
    ranges = {k: [] for k in df_dates['Code'].unique()}
    
    for i in range(len(df_dates)):
        row = df_dates.loc[i]
        ranges[row['Code']].append((row['Start Date'], row['End Date']))
    
    
    #Check if 'Timestamp' values are in the range and add a 'Yes, 'No' column
    within_boundary = []    
    for i in range(len(df_table)):
        row = df_table.loc[i]
        if row['Code'] in (ranges.keys()):
            
            if any(lower <= row['Timestamp'] <= upper for (lower, upper) in ranges[row['Code']]):
                within_boundary.append('Yes')
            else:
                within_boundary.append('No')
        else:
            within_boundary.append('NaN')
            
    
    df_table['Within_Boundary'] = within_boundary      
    


def function2():
    
    def filter_date(main_table, table_dates):
    
        idx = table_dates.Code == main_table.Code
        table_dates = table_dates.loc[idx]
        filtering = (table_dates['Start Date'] <= main_table.Timestamp) & (table_dates['End Date'] >= main_table.Timestamp)
        
        return filtering.any()
    
    
    # Example below
    df_table = pd.DataFrame({'Code':['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'], 'Timestamp':[1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2], 'Col1':np.arange(14), 'Col2':np.arange(14)})
    df_dates = pd.DataFrame({'Code':['A', 'A', 'B'], 'Start Date':[1, 5, 1], 'End Date':[2, 6, 3]})
            
    df_table['Exclude Date'] = df_table.apply(lambda x: filter_date(x, df_dates), axis=1)
    df_table = df_table[df_table['Exclude Date'] == False]
            

time1 = timeit.timeit(function1, number=1000)
time2 = timeit.timeit(function2, number=1000)

print("Function 1 took:", time1)
print("Function 2 took:", time2)

if time1 < time2:
     print(f"Function 1 is {((time2 - time1)/(time1+time2)) *100}% faster.")
else:
    print(f"Function 2 is {((time1 - time2)/(time1+time2))*100}% faster.")

Output:
Function 1 took: 3.649180000007618
Function 2 took: 20.820468800025992
Function 1 is 70.17382611553784% faster.

Implementing functions, such as to check if the Timestamp value exists in the range for that "code", can further improve the speed.

any mock tests to show this is a better approach?

It would be easier to do the mock test with the actual data. I can take this solution offline for now.

@Adeva1 So I run the code on the actual data: Adeva1's code completed in 274.26 seconds (4.5min) while the original code completed the task in 2480.79 seconds (41min)

You can try conditional_join from pyjanitor to join based on your condition and after that filter the rows that don't have have a match.
I reseted the index before the join in case you need the old index, but if you don't need it, you can remove "reset_index"
#pip install pyjanitor
import janitor

df = (df_table.reset_index().conditional_join(df_dates, 
     ('Code', 'Code', '=='),
     ('Timestamp', 'Start Date', '>='),
     ('Timestamp', 'End Date', '<='),
     how='left'))
result = df.loc[df[('right', 'Code')].isna(), df.columns[:5]].droplevel(0, axis=1)

A second option is to join only the rows that match your condition, and filter the rows that are in the joined dataframe.
df = (df_table.reset_index().conditional_join(df_dates, 
     ('Code', 'Code', '=='),
     ('Timestamp', 'Start Date', '>='),
     ('Timestamp', 'End Date', '<='),
     how='inner'))
m = df_table.index.isin(df[('left', 'index')])
result = df_table[~m]

End result:
index Code  Timestamp  Col1  Col2
     2    A          3     2     2
     3    A          4     3     3
     9    B          4     9     9
    10    B          5    10    10
    11    B          6    11    11
    12    C          1    12    12
    13    C          2    13    13

